# UTC_TIMESTAMP() VS. CONCAT(UTC_DATE(), ' ', UTC_TIME())

Tags: mariadb, utc

Are `UTC_TIMESTAMP ()` and `CONCAT (UTC_DATE (), '', UTC_TIME ())` functionally identical?

**EDIT:**

When I tested it, `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` does not return a UNIX TIMESTAMP. (with MariaDB 10.x)
[image]

Comment: use tags that are actually relevant, use MariaDB not MySQL

Comment: @Used_By_Already I'm sorry for that. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. UTC_TIMESTAMP returns a string or number, the CONCAT returns a string.

> UTC_TIMESTAMP, UTC_TIMESTAMP([fsp])
>
> Returns the current UTC date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, depending on whether the function
>   is used in a string or numeric context.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/utc_timestamp/

---

> CONCAT(str1,str2,...)
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/concat/

> ```
> create table test ( real_ts timestamp, fake_ts varchar(40));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (real_ts, fake_ts)
> values (utc_timestamp()+6, CONCAT (UTC_DATE (), '', UTC_TIME ()));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> real_ts             | fake_ts           
> :------------------ | :-----------------
> 2017-11-09 06:57:15 | 2017-11-0906:57:09
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (real_ts)
> values (utc_timestamp()+6)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (real_ts)
> values ( CONCAT (UTC_DATE (), '', UTC_TIME ())+6)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2017-11-0906:57:09'
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8d07a6de705638d4ab32d2d8be8920c3)*

Comment: So, if I use UTC_TIMESTAMP() only for **returning a string(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format)**, are they identical for me?

Comment: not identical (as you can see from the doco) but when both approaches are used as strings yu get the same strings from both. I know that is a subtle difference, bt it is different.

Comment: Now I see your intentions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would *not* trust the `CONCAT` (even if it would work).  What if the implementation called `UTC_DATE()` just before midnight, and called `UTC_TIME()` just after?  Oops, the combined string is off by a whole day!

Comment: I think the possibility of such a situation is very low, but it seems reasonable. There is a problem with strictness as you say.

Comment: I don't like insidious bugs that take days to figure out.  When I figure out the bug, I feel satisfied (at figuring it out) and stupid (for not preventing it in the first place).  Then I worry that the rest of my code is littered with other subtle bugs.